# Hadoop components to nodes mapping - what components should be installed where

Tags: hadoop, installation, hortonworks-data-platform

I am considering the following hadoop services for setting up a cluster using HDP 2.1

```
 - HDFS    
 - YARN    
 - MapReduce2    
 - Tez    
 - Hive    
 - WebHCat    
 - Ganglia   
 - Nagios    
 - ZooKeeper
```

There are 3 node types that I can think of

1. NameNodes (ex: primary, secondary)
2. Application Nodes (from where I will access hive service most often and also copy code repositories and any other code artifacts)
3. Data Nodes(The workhorses of the cluster)

Given above I know that there are these best practices and common denominators

- Zookeeper services should be running on atleast 3 data nodes
- DataNode service should be running on all data nodes
- Ganglia monitor should be running on all data nodes
- Name node service should be running on name nodes
- NodeManager should be installed on all nodes containing DataNode component.

This still leaves lots of open questions ex:

- which is the ideal node to install a lot the servers needed ex: Hive Server, App Timeline Server, WebHCat Server, Nagios Server, Ganglia Server, MySQL server. Is it Application nodes? should each get its own node? should we have a separate 'utilities' node?
- is there some criterion to choose where zookeeper should be installed?

I thinking the more generic question is there a table with "Hadoop components to nodes mapping essentially what components should be installed where"

Seeking advice/insight/links or documents on this topic.